# Convergence of an improper integral for parameter $a$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So I have to find for which $a\in \mathbb{R}$ te following improper integral converges:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2-2x-3)^{2a}}$$.

Okay so the integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2-2x-3)^{2a}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}}$$

So m first thought is to separate the integral like this:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}}=\int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}}+\int_{3}^{4}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}}+\int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}}$$

And look for converge of each one by itself.

So  is it correct to do it like this:

First for $a>1$, then $0<a<1$ and lastly $a<0$.

Lets say:
$0<a<1$
$$\int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{((x-3)(x+1))^{2a}} \leq \int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{((x)(x+x))^{2a}}=\int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{((2x^2)^{2a}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{2a}}\int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^{4a}}$$ So  this converges for $a>\frac{1}{4}$.
But how can I look at this integrals convergence for $a>0$ and $a<0$.
And is my approach correct?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The integral is not well-defined. $x^2-2x-3$ has a sign change when $x$ travels from $3^-$ o $3^+$. Was it $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\left|x^2-2x+3\right|^{2a}},$$ actually?

Comment: It's the way I wrote it, no absolute value.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of $(x^2-2x-3)^{2a}$ for $a=1/8$ and $x=1$?

Comment: I see the problem now, but it was as defined as it is.